# Reconnect multiple mongoose connections manually

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My app has two mongoose connections, a default connection using `mongoose.connect()` and another using the `mongoose.createConnection()` function.

This app was running for months without issues. The last two weeks I had an issue, something I still don't know broke the MongoDB connections.
To fix unexpected db disconnects I added a reconnect function to the default connection using `mongoose.connect()` again and it works fine, even the mongoose connection events work.

The problem is the secondary connection. It exports a model, and if I try to reconnect it using my reconnect function, but changing `mongoose.connect()` to `secondaryConnection = mongoose.createConnection()` it creates a completely new connection and the app tries to use the model of the previous connection (and also the events of the new connection don't work)

These are the two connections and the reconnect function

```
let reconnectAttempt = 0;

const reconnect = () => {
  try {
    reconnectAttempt++;

    if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 0) {
      console.log(
        `Trying to reconnect. Attempt: ${reconnectAttempt}`,
      );

      mongoose.connect(connectionString, mongooseOptions);

      if (reconnectAttempt >= 5) {
        console.log(`Reconnect failed`);
      } else {
        reconnect();
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const connectMongoPrimary = () => {
  try {
    mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
    mongoose.connect(connectionString, mongooseOptions);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", () => {
  reconnect();
});
```

```
secondaryConnection = mongoose.createConnection(
  connectionString,
  mongooseOptions,
);

const PhoneModel = secondaryConnection.model("Phone", PhoneSchema);

export { PhoneModel };
```

How can I reconnect manually the `secondaryConnection` without creating a new connection with `mongose.createConnection`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to address the issue with your app rather than create your own reconnect function. Mongoose will try to reconnect a connection for you when it loses connection to the database. Only if mongoose fails on initial connect then it doesn't try to reconnect so I suspect it's on initial connection your problem lies. The `mongose.createConnection` you created is scoped to the `PhoneModel` because you have adopted the "export model pattern" so `PhoneModel` queries will always use this single connection.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't reconnect automatically, that's why I added that function. The initial connection is successful, and the app runs without issues (beside the bug that broke the connections). How can I make mongoose reconnect automatically? And how can I change the export model pattern? I mean what other patterns are there. Thanks

Comment: The export pattern is fine. It's not necessarily a bad thing it just means the model is scoped to that connection but both ways can leverage the connection pool. When mongoose disconnects it will emit a `disconnected` event and try to reconnect. Read more [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connections).